# All my widgets in my xml file have turned red

Tags: java, xml, android-studio, dependencies

[image]
Last I remembered I included Picasso Dependency and this problem started . All my Layouts and widgets have turned red and I can't work properly. I noticed one thing as well that Button widget shows error but `AppCompatButton` works fine. I am also getting the notification  - code insight unavailable (script configuration wasn't received )
[image]

I tried changing the dependencies on my own still the errors showed up, removed Picasso dependency because the problem started from there but no result. **Note - My app works fine for the code I have written before this error , now it does not load widgets and layout for the new code.**

Is there a way to solve this issue?

[image]

Comment: Turned red? I don't see any in the screenshot. Can you elaborate?

Comment: try to rebuild the project, or invalidate caches and restart

Comment: Ok , I got the solution for this problem. It all happened due to a dependency that I added in early stages of my App . Still I don't have an idea why it created a problem after so many days